# Update a column with count from another table: My query is not working. I am getting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Scorecard table:

| lsp | werks | Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | ZZZ |  |
| BBB | YYY |  |
| CCC | XXX |  |

Inventory table:

| lsp | werks | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | ZZZ | SUCCESS |
| AAA | ZZZ | SUCCESS |
| AAA | ZZZ | SUCCESS |
| AAA | ZZZ | SUCCESS |
| BBB | YYY | SUCCESS |
| BBB | YYY | SUCCESS |
| BBB | YYY | SUCCESS |
| BBB | YYY | FAILURE |

I want to write a query to update the `Scorecard` table with count of success from the `Inventory` table on a defined lsp

This is my query in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE [Scorecard] 
SET Success = (SELECT COUNT([INVENTORY].[Status]) 
               FROM [INVENTORY]  
               WHERE [INVENTORY].STATUS = SUCCESS 
                 AND [INVENTORY].[werks] = [Scorecard].[werks])
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Please [edit] your question and add some details.

Comment: Generally you *shouldn't* store this type of information; as soon as a row is inserted, updated or deleted the `COUNT` value is out of date. This means you either often have stale data, have to have some process to constantly update the table, or implement triggers. You'll be better off creating a `VIEW`.

Comment: Agree with Larnu. If the read performance is an issue, use an indexed view.

Answer (score 1):

as it has been mentioned in the comments , there is a big design issue , but to answer your question:

```
UPDATE [Scorecard] 
SET Success = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [INVENTORY]  
        WHERE [INVENTORY].STATUS = 'SUCCESS'
        AND [INVENTORY].[werks] = [Scorecard].[werks]
        AND [INVENTORY].[lsp] = [Scorecard].[lsp]
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way. I have taken count over the partition of werk.

```
 SELECT 
  COUNT (1) OVER (PARTITION BY Werks ORDER by   lsp ) AS [num]
  ,Werks
 INTO #Temp_A
 FROM       [INVENTORY] 
 WHERE [Status] ='SUCCESS'


UPDATE A
   SET Success = B.num
 FROM  [Scorecard] A
 INNER JOIN  #Temp_A B ON A.Werks =  B.Werks 

DROP TABLE #Temp_A
```

[image: Result]